# Change Display Name of Usr Field After Publish

Tags: customization, acumatica

I am working with a new screen that is using a the DAC and Graph of the Inventory Item table. When I add a field into the form header that is a Usr custom field it has the name that has already been assigned in the a different customization project. How can I change this name in the new customization project. I have tried going through the customize attribute but it does not show up in the fields that I can select. Is there a way to do it through Graph or DAC code or even dynamically? I am just updating the display name not the data type of anything like that. I have tried going through the Label Text property but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the DAC field DisplayName attribute in your graph using CacheAttached method.

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Display Name")]
protected virtual void DAC_UsrField_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
}
```